# Issues when trying to import svg image in android studio

Tags: android, svg, design-patterns

When I m trying to import a svg image as a vector asset in my android studio project, I can see no preview of the svg and the android studio says that the image may be incomplete due to encountered issues (image 1).
[image: Configure vector asset window]
[image: Conversion issues window]

When I click on the issues I see a window about conversion issues that says that the encountered issues are:
ERROR @ line 41: <pattern> is not supported
ERROR @ line 51: <image> is not supported
(image 2)
What can I do to fix these issues and succeed in importing the svg image in my project?

Comment: Remove all the patterns

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: With an editor.